# SQL selecting data between particular date and additional field filter

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the a sql table `payments` with the following columns:

```
id|name|amount|reference_number|payment_date|status
```

And here is some values

```
1|John Doe|10.00|123456G|2019-02-21 08:00:21|confirmed
2|John Doe|10.00|FHFHgJJ|2019-02-21 10:05:50|pending
3|John Doe|10.00|57GHHFG|2019-02-22 12:10:32|pending
4|John Doe|10.00|GHTYNHJ|2019-02-22 09:52:26|confirmed
5|John Doe|10.00|123G456|2019-02-23 12:22:45|confirmed
6|John Doe|10.00|J123456|2019-02-23 13:00:21|pending
```

Now I need to fetch select the data based on `payment_date` and `status` where sometimes the `payment_date` can be a range or the same date.

Scenario 1:

```
SELECT * 
FROM payments 
WHERE payment_date >= '2019-02-21' AND payment_date <= '2019-02-21' AND status='confirmed' 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Should return:

```
1|John Doe|10.00|123456G|2019-02-21 08:00:21|confirmed
```

Screnario 2:

```
SELECT * 
FROM payments 
WHERE payment_date >= '2019-02-21' AND payment_date <= '2019-02-23' AND status='confirmed' 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Should return:

```
1|John Doe|10.00|123456G|2019-02-21 08:00:21|confirmed
4|John Doe|10.00|GHTYNHJ|2019-02-22 09:52:26|confirmed
5|John Doe|10.00|123G456|2019-02-23 12:22:45|confirmed
```

Any work around this?

Comment: payment_date >= '2019-02-21 00:00:00' AND payment_date <= '2019-02-23 23:59:59'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @strawberry suggested use time as well with date to fetch the data

```
SELECT * 
FROM payments 
WHERE payment_date >= '2019-02-21 00:00:00' AND payment_date <= '2019-02-21 
23:59:59' AND status='confirmed' 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `+ interval 1 day` for the end date and change `<=` to `<`, like this:

```
SET @startdate = '2019-02-21';
SET @enddate = '2019-02-21';

SELECT * 
FROM payments 
WHERE 
  payment_date >= @startdate 
  AND 
  payment_date < @enddate + interval 1 day
  AND 
  status='confirmed' 
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tYt9EzgAkk2Mka43jutZJg/0)